# Seeking an appropriate response to "bienvenue"

Tags: expressions, usage, salutations

Welsh friend living in Brittany and struggling to learn French, responded to me accepting his Facebook 'friend request' with "well well well bienvenue". What is an appropriate French response?

Comment: IMO a simple "merci" is enough ;)

Answer (score 4):

« Bienvenu ! » is a pretty direct translation of "Welcome!" and gets the same direct response you would give in English, in which case you have several options -

> « Merci ! »
>
> « Merci beaucoup ! »
>
> « Merci bien ! »